# Numbering Question Help Me!

Tags: sectioning, numbering, roman

I don't know if my explanation is correct, but I'd like to make the following documents

This is about numbering.
I'm trying it myself, but... I think this is too difficult for me.
Can you tell me how to make a document like this?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @hoodie Can you change the title of your question to reflect what your question is about? In its current the state the title will make it very difficult for future users with the same problem to find your question and the nice answers you got

Answer (score 4):

As long as indenting of section headings is not an issue, the following could be a starting point:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{(\arabic{subsubsection})}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph})}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\arabic{subparagraph})}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \csname @ifpackageloaded\endcsname{hyperref}{%
    % \theH... -macros are used ny hyperref's automatic creating of
    % anchor-names/destination-names for hyperlinking. Anchor-names/
    % destination-names must be unique within the document.
    \renewcommand\theHsection{\thesection}%
    \renewcommand\theHsubsection{\theHsection\thesubsection}%
    \renewcommand\theHsubsubsection{\theHsubsection\thesubsubsection}%
    \renewcommand\theHparagraph{\theHsubsubsection\theparagraph}%
    \renewcommand\theHsubparagraph{\theHparagraph\thesubparagraph}%
  }{}%
}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph (maybe?)}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\section{Second Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't care about indenting!
That's what I wanted!
Thanks a lot!

I've been working on this all week...
I really appreciate the excellent reply.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use **paragraph** to make a **subsubsubsection**, code is as follows:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}{\paragraph}  %define newcommand \subsubsubsection
```

**Outcome**:

[image]

The above reslut achieved can be found in: https://github.com/wanzhenchn/Programming_Assignments_of_Deep_Learning

Comment: I didn't know there was a way.
I thought only 'paragraph' could come after 'subsubsection'. 
Thank you very much for your answer!